# Extract Excel metadata in Linux

Tags: extract

I have used the "extract" command, but it never was able to find as much information as FOCA found on these Excel spreadsheets I am dealing with.

For example, I am using the FOCA application to harvest and download files from the web. Afterwards, it is extracting metadata from all of the files.

With regards to Excel files, it appears that these files are containing more metadata than the average PDF file. That being said, FOCA is able to detect printer names, email addresses, and a few other things that are stored within this spreadsheet file. However, I cannot find any way to get this same information in Linux using the "extract" command.

Is there a way to extract files within Linux and grab ALL of its metadata? Seems like the extract command may be limited from what I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Excel files store a lot of meta data within the file, so you would have to parse the file itself to get at it.  Since you're on Linux and can't use the Excel interop, you could try to use an Excel library like [ExcelWriter](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/DocumentProperties) or something similar.  ExcelWriter is written for .Net, so you'd have to use mono.

Comment: Hmm, kk. Not sure what "mono" is but I'm going to look into this ExcelWriter library. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: smoor, would you happen to have an idea of where I could start reading about how to extract metadata files within Linux? I took a look at the ExcelWriter page you linked, but I don't understand what this would have to do with Python, or even how to manually extract metadata from excel files in linux.